# How do I match numbers on two sheets and output into a third using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write some VBA that will find the matching numbers that appear in both Sheet 1 and Sheet 2, and output them to Sheet 3. My code is below, but is producing no result. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Sub match()
    Dim a As Integer
    dim i as long, ii as long
    a = 2

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ylastrow As Long
    ylastow = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    for i = a to lastrow
    for ii = a to ylastrow
    if Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii,2) then
    Sheets("Sheet3").range("A100000").xlup

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the matching cells copied into sheet3 by rows continuously

You are missing `next ii` and `next i` and `end if` also your destination cell in sheet3 is not set right 
this should work

```
Sub match()
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Long, ii As Long, j As Long
a = 2
j = 2

Dim lastrow As Long

Dim ylastrow As Long

Sheet1rows = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
sheet2rows = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

For i = a To Sheet1rows
    For ii = a To sheet2rows
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ii, 1) Then
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
        End If
    Next ii
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks worked perfect but just wana to know what you mean by this
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) i understand the first part but sheets(sheet1) how come you didnt use sheet2 instead  once again thanks a lot

Comment: you can use either sheet1 or sheet2 they have same value at that point.